# How in react-router-dom can I get the `previous` as in react-navigation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-navigation, react-router-dom

I am using [`react-navigation`](https://reactnavigation.org/) 5 and [`react-router-dom`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web),

We use the `previous` to define if we should define a `back` button. We want to have something equivalent in `react-router`.

```js
function App() {
    const { previous, goBack, toggleDrawer } = useNavigation();
    return (
      <div>
        {previous ? (
          <Button
            onPress={goBack}
          />
        ) : (
          <Button
            icon="menu"
            onPress={toggleDrawer}
            accessibilityLabel="toggle drawer menu"
          />
        )}
      </div>
    );
}
```

How in `react-router-dom` can I get the `previous` as in `react-navigation`? (as in `const { previous } = useNavigation();`

Comment: you want to use react router with your reactjs  website Right ?? not in react-native

Comment: That's right, I am already using react-router in my reactjs website. I just am trying to port a utility that would interface both navigation and I can't get a `previous` equivalent in RR5!

Comment: AFAIK, `react-router-dom` does not, but two patterns I've used are (1) add a "from path" state value to every route push, or (2) keep a "history stack" in app state, i.e. redux or similar.

Comment: I use `connected-react-router` that use redux for storing state.

Answer (score 1):

I created a history reducer to track the last N history entries. This implementation is a "stack" with the "top" always at index 0, "top" being the current location, i.e. the route you just pushed, therefore index 1 would be the previous location.

```
import { LOCATION_CHANGE } from 'connected-react-router';

const HISTORY_LENGTH = 10;

const initialState = [];

const locationReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  const { type } = action;

  switch (type) {
    case LOCATION_CHANGE: {
      const { payload } = action;
      if (
        state.length &&
        state[0].location.pathname === payload.location.pathname
      ) {
        // if pushing same route, return old state
        return state;
      }

      switch (payload.action) {
        case 'REPLACE':
          // if replacing current entry, don't "push" on new route, replace "top"
          return [payload, ...state.slice(1)];

        // handle other action cases to maintain your stack

        default: // PUSH
          // ensure only last HISTORY_LENGTH entries kept
          return [payload, ...state].slice(0, HISTORY_LENGTH);
      }
    }

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default locationReducer;
```

`LOCATION_CHANGE` is an [action](https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router/blob/master/src/actions.js) defined by `connected-react-router`, which is dispatched when your history receives a location change.

Each `payload` has the following shape:

```
{
  location,
  action,
  isFirstRendering,
}
```

If you are looking to selectively render a "back" button then you can examine the stack and if there are more than 1 entries you can assert there exists a page to go back to.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I assume it will be the main entry of the current switch and because of that, not displaying the back button?  (like I do with `react-navigation`_)

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa Ok, if I'm understanding your question, you are asking about one of the `switch` statements. The outer switch consumes the action `LOCATION_CHANGED` which is defined in `connected-react-router`, the inner switch consumes the history action from the payload, so you know to add/remove/replace entries in your stack, i.e. maintain your stack. To render a back button just check how many entries you have in your stack.

Comment: How do you check how many entries in your stack and where do you store them? redux? I believe something similar to what you have post, but with dynamic store creation and some utilities to read into them the previous state?

Comment: in `react-navigation`, you can have multiple navigation, each with one entrypoint. While in `react-router`, do you think I can get the same behavior by catching all the entrypoint of a `<Switch>` or is there side effect I have not thinked about ?

Comment: Ok, since you are using `connected-react-router` you are also using redux. The above is a redux reducer that listens for location changes and keeps a history stack in your app state. Access it like any other piece of state in the `react-redux` `connect` HOC, `state.pathHistory.length > 0` for example, if you name the reducer `pathHistory` in the `combineReducers` decorator. TBH I don't quite follow your second question about entry points. Seems unrelated to keeping a route history history.

Comment: In a native app, you can have 10 stack each stack are different. This means they have their own history, each stack has a new homepage (or entrypoint). This way, you can go back to the home of your stack. In RR5, you can nest Switch and Routes. The entrypoint is the `basePath`, generally `/`, if you nest root, for example with a stack with a namespace called `customer`, then `/customer` will be the entrypoint, `/customer/1` a Route, etc... This means one history isn't enough. I don't  understand  myself how it should  work, question is theorical, if you do understand how react-navigation work

Comment: Browsers have a single history (per window/tab), and `react-router-dom` works in a browser. I also can't find any reference to `previous` in the [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/next/navigation-prop.html) docs.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your path to next screen as state using Link

```
 const { location } = props;  // if you are not getting location as props then use withRouter with your component 

<Link 
  to={{ pathname: '/nextpath',
  state: { prevPath: location.pathname }}}>
  go to next page 
</Link>
```

Access your prevPath in next screen

```
this.props.location.state
```